# Nested Requests in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

When creating a rest service using Spring Boot, a @GetMapping is done for a specific path. I try to make a normal HTTP request from that point and I get all sort of exceptions: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/message/TokenParser` or the error:`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host is null`, etc., depending how I try to go around it. I understand in principle the issue, but did not find a solution. I attach the sample code:

The **@GetMapping** looks like this:

```
  @GetMapping("/requesttest")
  public String TestRequest(@RequestParam("requestlink") String requestlink ) throws Exception {
    String requesttext = RHRequest.getHRequest(requestlink);
    return requesttext;
  }
```

The **request** class:

```
public class RHRequest {
  public static String getHRequest(String urlRequest) throws Exception {

    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(urlRequest);
    HttpClient httpClientRequest = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContextRequest = new BasicHttpContext();
    ResponseHandler<String> handlerRequest = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBodyRequest = null;
    HttpResponse responseHRequest = httpClientRequest.execute(httpRequest, localContextRequest);
    responseBodyRequest = handlerRequest.handleResponse(responseHRequest);
    return responseBodyRequest.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of Apache HttpClient do you use? Can you provide your pom.xml of client and server?

Comment: I used:
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4'. And yes, that was the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.

Apparently, the SSLContexts class has been relocated to another package in httpclient 4.4, along with other modifications. I upgraded my httpcore version 4.4 and httpclient to 4.5 and issue was fixed.

Another problem was that the link I used for request should have been encoded.